# Move `Go to definition` results to bottom in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

In Visual Studio 2022, there is `Find Symbol Results` window so that if I disable `Open definition in peek view` and Ctrl+Click to the function, it will list all the references in this window. Is there anything similar to it in Visual Studio Code instead of peek view? I find it kinda annoying when the peek view pops up right at the cursor.

Also the `References` view doesnt show anything.